# Not able to retrieve the id, access tokens from the uri after redirecting

Tags: python, flask, amazon-cognito

I am using hosted UI for login in AWS Cognito, after successfully signed in, I am not able to take the id_token and access token from the url

```
http://localhost:5000/upload#id_token=eyJraWQiOiJDOWtTMmxRXC9VQ2hwN3lNVnY1YWtuU0N5M245Wm1UVG1Dempvd2c1Mm9SUT0iLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.VBd4aVzh7Lk2TxAtqrG9rC1oOe05d5Kh7Z0Yx6DEeQaJm3M8IL9V1IYBynC51oRXVmxowfZEuppzJSxlNaHg6u6Gpc6ICO7QV9F9CH1YYmnXJmQlSEhN95gbCG7E8NmyjsWh_0DL1aByWw9A08tAL5A-fgzUVaS7Hl28XHAmVdEvkc_ZpWo9zfYSs1-UX9OV_SqO0vKiu3-ZcZPj7471eyC4OYexRKBkevom7JDhg_0GLlnoxk1NpVxQa_lvlle_l_YlEJXMbMQ5vRgZr22ooVtXlmjz_jQTv16Jw_rcGEOEXo4mYC40ePyYc-Lw9HGnHI1sWDEbYMzhdcihRWc08w&access_token=eyJraWQiOiJQaDBHRVQrSStyTjRaZnloOHJKekM2aHhwYURwUmlFaU5ZMVlZRlQ0M2FjPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.HdVnOiGuLS3ZjEb6XaMQHSGizqwrimIShq2xfuRtMBOdudblhTBMjSeQReqcOoGt2YRRiDGVpdGWE2-jhXAGEK-Z-0SDR1WmGnTgslwj8vQQjvRhX2JYtzKwClJ68dT427Jhe6m1_aJAOx0inzXM57FQDUrzRMLf4kv5JsF6Xm1mBOMWOmnQye7cbyaAhwKNGGQkVfY37XBCbHBVRhtwEc01HXpLX5TEbNytz73sobURu7YrB1_a4qPH49ZNHzIlM6k3sVSPIuRC6I7ynAlI-T9eAFTa0H9bvsKZLNNMDbHJmcKT1yOZuNfoaAlhHfvoXnSRcf7L5tciHHgQNOMcTA&expires_in=3600&token_type=Bearer
```

Domain string:

```
f'https://******.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id=**********&response_type=token&scope=openid&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5000/callback
```

when i print `requests.url` only the main url till `http://localhost:5000/upload` is printing, the id tokens and access tokens are not present during printing and if i split the above url with '#' in python and accessing the first element . I am getting index out of range error

Comment: The `#` part of a URL is not sent to the server, it's used only by the client. URL query parameters are indicated with `?`

Comment: After successful sign in, I was properly redirected to the specified URI along with the access tokens sent by the server to me. I understand it is (#) not a query param, but it is present on the URL right, How can I access these tokens following the "#"?  These tokens are sent from cognito to me right?

Comment: No, it's NOT in the URL. The client removes it from the URL when it sends to the server.

Comment: Right ok, The access tokens are only visible to us, when the client sends the request to the server these tokens are removed by the client and then sent to the server. So, the server won't be aware of our tokens. Correct??

Comment: That's correct.